# inspect module for python

Tags: python, inspect

I'm an artist that is new to python/coding in general, and also have trouble reading this doc.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#

I am trying to understand how to use the `inspect` module.
This file is called TestClassA.py:

```
import inspect

class TestClassA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "this is crazy!"

    print inspect.isclass(TestClassA)
    #result is True
```

What I'm trying to do is to return `TestClassA` and everything in it.  The basic concept is to copy my code and have it pop out as a message

```
print inspect.getsource(TestClassA)
```

Result is:

```
TypeError: <module '__main__' (built-in)> is a built-in class
```

But this is Funny. if i use:

```
print inspect.isclass(TestClassA)
```

the result is True.

So my ultimate goal is to copy a specific type of classes into text (reminder: multiple of classes can be under one .py file) and bring that specific type of class in to another .py file.

Can anyone help me out? I would highly appreciate if anyone can also set an example on how `inspect.getsourcefile` and `inspect.getsourcelines` work using the same simple example above.

Comment: "when i want to Copy my class in to a string" - what do you mean by copying a class into a string? And if you have a string instead of a class, why would you expect `inspect` to treat it as a class?

Comment: Do you get an error?  If so, can you post the full traceback?  According to the docs, `the argument may be a module, class, method, function ...`, so it should work.

Comment: hi user2357112 i'm trying to copy my class and returning the entire class as a result.

Comment: If you're new to Python, why are you trying to do that? What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: Hi keith and mgilson i have edit my question.

Comment: Are you running this in an interactive shell?

Comment: I think @RushyPanchal's onto something. I can reproduce the error in the question if I type in a class in an interactive shell and inspect it directly, but not if I've put it in a module and run the module. The issue seems to be that `__main__` is a special builtin module object when the interpreter is run interactively with no code. Something in `inspect.getsource` doesn't play well with that special builtin module object.

Comment: This looks like it's a known bug in Python: https://bugs.python.org/issue12920  At the very least, the error message is misleading. Perhaps the whole thing could be fixed though....

Comment: So RushyPanchal's and @Blckknght both of you can be right. So i use _Sublime Text_ as my IDE and my interactive shell is _Maya2016_ (a 3D software). imma going to look into this a little bit more. but yeah **getting the class wont work.. but getting the other modules in a class does work.**

Answer (score 2):

```
import inspect

class TestClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        print "Hello"
print inspect.getsource(TestClassA)
```

Workig for me in pycharm, If you try to use it in interactive mode,run this

```
import os
import inspect
inspect.getsource(os)
```

Two methods you mentioned does the same thing only return types are different
Check https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsourcelines